# how to print all values from an array containing a given string value (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Given an array like the below code **:**

```
let words = ['bring','constant','bath','spring','splashing']
```

How do I print all string characters with `ing` characters from the `words` array ?

Comment: Try filtering. See **[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

Comment: Filter array which contains `ing` using `includes`. Simple. You should should what you have tried

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `endsWith` method to check if the word ends with a specific value.

```js
let words = ['bring','constant','bath','spring','splashing']

const result = words.filter(w => w.endsWith('ing'))

result.forEach(w => console.log(w))
```

You also can use regular expressions with dollar sign `$` means end with.

```js
let words = ['bring','constant','bath','spring','splashing']

const result = words.filter(w => /(ing)$/.test(w))

result.forEach(w => console.log(w))
```

Comment: thanks Mina...one more question... would you have to just change the argument passed in endsWith() if the given string value is in the middle part of the elements in the array??

Comment: You are welcome, `endsWith` just if the value at the end of the string, but if you want to check in the middle, you can use `includes` to check if the word contains that value whatever if it at the start or middle or the end of the word

Comment: it worked...you are a jem ;)

Answer (score 0):

As author want to check if `ing` exist in the middle of the word or not. In that case you can just use normal regex with [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method without `$` sign at end.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let words = ['bring','constant','bath','spring','splashing', 'tingtong'];

const res = words.filter(word => word.match(/ing/ig));

console.log(res);
```

Or you can also achieve that by using [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let words = ['bring','constant','bath','spring','splashing', 'tingtong'];

const res = words.filter(word => word.includes('ing'));

console.log(res);
```